# In SQL replace null value with another value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

Here is my SQL Query

```
SELECT p.StudentID, ai.RollNo, p.FirstName, p.MiddleName, p.LastName, 
om.ExamID,  et.ExamName, om.SubjectID,
ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(20),om.ObtainedMarksTheory), 'A') as 'ObtainedMarksTheory', 
ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(20),om.ObtainedPracticalMarks),'A') as 'ObtainedPracticalMarks'
FROM Students.PersonalInfo p
INNER JOIN Students.AcademicCourse ac on p.StudentID = ac.StudentID
INNER JOIN Students.AcademicInfo ai on p.StudentID=ai.StudentID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Exam.ObtainedMarkEntry om on p.StudentID = om.StudentID
LEFT JOIN Exam.ExamType et   on om.ExamID = et.ExamID
WHERE ai.BatchID = '103' AND ai.SemesterID = '21' and ac.Section = '8'
```

This produce result as in a picture:

[image]

But I want result like this since those two students were absent in that exam

[image]

Similarly if another Exam does exists for any of three student and other are absent same procedure should repeat

Comment: Can you please explain the logic behind the output your trying to achieve? where are those "default" values coming from?

Comment: In this particular result set student are enrolled in exam. In above result student with rollno 1 has attended Exam with ExamID 28 but rest of the two have not attended it but the exam was compulsory. So that ExamID, ExamName, SubjectID field should populate to those students too who didn't attended. Rest of two columns with value A indicates absent.

Comment: Something wrong happened with the images. They too became NULL

Answer (score 1):

Use IsNULL() Function see below example

```
Declare @variable varchar(MAX)
set @variable = NULL
select IsNULL(@variable,0) as A
```

[image]

Comment: I think I simply can't do this. because isnull replace null field with some known static value in this case 0 but In my case I don't know with what value I have to replace that null field. But what I know is;  a field which contains value , that value should pass to null fields

Comment: @user42392, use `ISNULL(ColumnContainedNULL, ColumnWhichReplaceNULLValue`)

Answer (score 0):

Let's have the following sample data (it is like your sample data, just inserted in one table):

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [StudentID] TINYINT
   ,[RowNo] TINYINT
   ,[FirstName] VARCHAR(12)
   ,[MiddleName] VARCHAR(12)
   ,[LastName] VARCHAR(12)
   ,[ExamID] TINYINT
   ,[ExamName] VARCHAR(18)
   ,[SubjectID] TINYINT
   ,[ObtainedMarksTheory] VARCHAR(12)
   ,[ObtainedPracticalMarks] VARCHAR(12)
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([StudentID], [RowNo], [FirstName], [MiddleName], [LastName], [ExamID], [ExamName], [SubjectID], [ObtainedMarksTheory], [ObtainedPracticalMarks])
VALUES (101, 1, 'FN_A', 'MN_A', 'LN_A', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'A', 'A')
      ,(102, 2, 'FN_B', 'MN_B', 'LN_B', 28, 'First Tem2072', 97, '74.00', '56.00')
      ,(103, 3, 'FN_C', 'MN_C', 'LN_C', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'A', 'A');

SELECT *
FROM @DataSource;
```

[image]

So, I am supposing we have details only for one exam here and the question is how to replace the `NULL` values of `ExamID`, `ExamName` and `SubjectID` columns using the existing values.

The solution is to use the `MAX` function with `OVER` clause:

```
SELECT [StudentID]
      ,[RowNo]
      ,[FirstName]
      ,[MiddleName]
      ,[LastName]
      ,MAX([ExamID]) OVER() AS [ExamID]
      ,MAX([ExamName]) OVER() AS [ExamName]
      ,MAX([SubjectID]) OVER() AS [SubjectID]
      ,[ObtainedMarksTheory]
      ,[ObtainedPracticalMarks]
FROM @DataSource;
```

[image]

Note, that it is better to use the `OVER` clause as you are not going to add `GROUP BY` clauses in your initial query. Also, if you have details for more exams you can use the `PARTITION BY` clause (if you have some column(s) to distinguish the `NULL` rows for each exam).

Comment: Ok I will try this in my query. And yes I have to show more exam results too.

Comment: @user42392 OK, you need to add to your sample data a column or columns by which to distinguish the exams. Another solution will be to order the results by some columns. Could you edit your question and add such data/output?